# Inline assembly in C - Understand the compilation result

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to understand what will be the compilation result of the following code in c:

```
int ppid;
#define SYS_getppid 23
asm volatile("int %1" : "=a" (ppid) : "i" (T_SYSCALL), "a" (SYS_getppid));
```

Where T_SYSCALL is the constant 64.

That's what I came up with so far:

```
?                            // I know something is missing here but I'm not sure what it is
mov $(SYS_getppid), %eax     // "a" (SYS_getppid)
int $(T_SYSCALL)             // T_SYSCALL = 64 in xv6
?                            // I know something is missing here but I'm not sure what it is
```

I'm not sure what to do with the ppid variable. Where should I save it when it is declared and how should I assign a value to this variable in the result of the inline assembly code (I guess I should use indirect addressing somewhere).

Notice I tried to use the GCC complier in order to create an assembly file out of the c file but the result is too complicated and I'm not sure I understand it correctly (I'm trying to come up with the most simple compilation result).

Also I read about inline assembly in the GNU website (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C) so I do understand the inline assembly syntax.

Can you please give me an hint how to complete the result compilation I wrote above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two input operands, and you have correctly handled both of them so there is nothing missing at the beginning.

You have one output variable, `ppid`, which uses constraint `a` and you already know that refers to the `eax` register. What this means is the compiler expects the value for `ppid` to be in `eax` after the asm block. Thus something like `movl %eax, ppid`, or, if `ppid` is a local variable, then of course use the correct offset from `esp` or `ebp` such as `movl %eax, 4(%esp)`.

Comment: So when you write "int ppid" the compiler doesn't generate any assembly code manipulating the registers?

Comment: Not as such, no, but at the beginning of the function it will allocate space for all the local variables. So in that sense, yes, there is something at the beginning, namely a `subl $4, %esp` where the amount allocated depends on the size of all the local variables and the alignment requirements of the platform.